# Can an elderly Kohen have a relationship with a concubine?

Tags: kohen-priest, concubine

There is no marriage Min Hatorah. There will be no children.

Rav Yaacov Emden seems to permit this. The reason is that widows are too rare and not easily available, causing other sins

Comment: Hi Jascana, welcome to Mi Yodeya and great to have you learning with us. Since MY might be different than other StackExchange-sites, you might want to have a look here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/conduct. Your question can be greatly improved if you could add in a citation of Rav Emden, where did you find this?